# Can a Hash have duplicate keys or values

Tags: perl, hash

Can a Hash have duplicate keys or values?

Comment: Did you mean hash table?

Comment: Oh didn't realize that hash is Perl's name for associative arrays (weird).

Comment: @Jake T., Perl associative arrays are hash tables

Comment: It is called a hash because of the hashing function used to associate keys with values

Comment: @ikegami: Yeah, but the name of the data structure doesn't even appear in your code so what's the point of shortening hash table to hash?

Comment: @Jake T., Why is `ls` not `list`?

Comment: @Eric: That's not correct. The hash function aids the search for the key in a table, it doesn't get you all the way to the value.

Comment: @Jake T., He didn't describe the whole structure, but what he said is correct. (I thought you were talking to me at first since my name is Eric too!)

Comment: @Jake T => I wrote a comment about the name `hash`, which is short for "`hash` table", which is short for "a data structure implemented with a `hash`ing function used to map arbitrary strings to the indices of an array of buckets, each containing a short linked list of the key value pairs, which are compared using string comparison to the requested key.  if the linked list gets long enough, the array of buckets is extended, the corresponding mapping between strings and indices is updated, and the data is reshuffled.  optimal solutions will work to minimize the effect of this".

Comment: From [perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/10/01/hashes.html): Perl's use of the term "hash" is the source of some potential confusion, because the output of a hashing function is also sometimes called a hash (especially in cryptographic contexts), and because hash tables aren't usually called hashes anywhere else.

To be on the safe side, refer to the data structure as a hash table, and use the term "hash" only in obvious, Perl-specific contexts.

Comment: @Jake T., So? Seeing as crypto hashes have neither keys nor values, there is no confusion in the OP's request. Furthermore, the context was Perl-specific.

Comment: @ikegami: I agree. I'm not criticizing OP. He tagged his question Perl and Hash is the name of the thing he is asking about. I'm just remarking on the strange choice of name for Perl's structure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it can have duplicate values but not keys.

Answer (score 11):

For both hashes and arrays, only one scalar can be stored at a given key. ("Keys are unique.") If they weren't, you couldn't do

```
$h{a} = 1;
$h{a} = 2;
$val = $h{a};  # 2

$a[4] = 1;
$a[4] = 2;
$val = $a[4];  # 2
```

If you wanted to associate multiple values with a key, you could place a reference to an array (or hash) at that key, and add the value to that array (or hash).

```
for my $n (4,5,6,10) {
    if ($n % 2) {
        push @{ $nums{odd} }, $n;
    } else {
        push @{ $nums{even} }, $n;
    }
}

say join ', ', @{ $nums{even} };
```

See [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) for more on this.

As for values, multiple elements can have the same value in both hashes and arrays.

```
$counts{a} = 3;
$counts{b} = 3;

$counts[5] = 3;
$counts[6] = 3;
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming talking about a "%hash"

Then:

- Duplicate keys not allowed.
- Duplicate values allowed.

This is easy to reason about because it is a mapping of a *particular* Key to a *particular* Value where the Value plays no part in the look-up and is thus independent upon other Values.

Answer (score 3):

Please try and run this code, it executes without errors.
I hope this is what you were asking!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ('a' => 1, 'a' => 2, 'b' => 4 );

print values %hash, "\n\n";
print keys %hash, "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Hash::MultiKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash%3a%3aMultiKey) module from CPAN.

(I used Data::Dumper to show how hash is exactly looks - it is not necessary here)

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Hash::MultiKey;

tie my %multi_hash, 'Hash::MultiKey';

$multi_hash{['foo', 'foo', 'baz']} = "some_data";

for (keys %multi_hash) {
    print @$_,"\n";
};

print Dumper\%multi_hash;
```

And the output shoud be () :

```
foofoobaz
$VAR1 = {
          'ARRAY(0x98b6978)' => 'some_data'
        };
```

So technically speaking Hash::MultiKey let you create reference as a hash key.

Answer (score -1):

Yes a hash can have duplicate keys as I demonstrate below...

Key example:    BirthDate|LastNameFirst4Chars|FirstNameInitial|IncNbr
                       "1959-12-19|Will|K|1" ... "1959-12-19|Will|K|74".
       Note: This might be a useful Key for record look ups if someone did not remember their Social Security Nbr

```
   #-- CODE SNIPPET:
   @Offsets=();     #-- we will build an array of Flat File record "byte offsets" to random access
                    #-- for all records matching this ALT KEY with DUPS       
   for ($i=1; $i<=99; $i++) {
       $KEY=$BirthDate . "|" . $LastNameFirst4Chars . "|" . $FirstNameInitial . "|" . $i; 
       if (exists $Hash{$KEY}) {
           push @Offsets, $Hash{$KEY};  #-- add another hash VALUE to the end of the array
       }
   }
```

Comment: What does this demonstrate? After your code has run, both `@Offsets` and `%Hash` are unchanged (i.e. still empty). The code simply generates 99 _different_ values for the variable `$KEY`, like `blabla|1`, `blabla|2`, ... `blabla|99`.

Comment: Ok, but standard hashes in Perl can definitely not have duplicate keys. The keys from your example are all different. `"$BirthDate|...|1"` is different from `"$BirthDate|...|2"`, isn't it? So the keys are _not_ duplicate.

Comment: PerlDuck, the sequence number makes the key unique.  If I have a Unique Primary Key let's say Social Security Number.  And I want to access a record in my database, but the SSN is not remembered, then I can use an ALT KEY w/DUPS such as:   "$BirthDate|$LastNameFirst4Chars|$FirstNameInitial|SeqNbr".   "1959-12-19|Will|K|1 ... "1959-12-19|Will|K|99".   All the data in the KEY is duplicated except for the sequence nbr.   That is how you enable a hash to have Duplicate Keys.